# Shouldn't text inside a web component be possible to select?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html-select, web-component

I just tested a new web component in Chrome and Firefox. To my surprise the text in the web component was not possible to select in Chrome. It is possible to select the text in Firefox.

And I was not able to change that in Chrome (using `user-select:text`).

This looks like a bug in Chrome to me, but maybe I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information on your web component. Share some implementation details, explain what it does or maybe make a demo with Codepen, JSFiddle etc. Here is a simple web component I created that displays the text "web component". The text is selectable in Chrome. [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/niiyeboah/pen/xxGVMZB)

Comment: @niiyeboah Thanks, you are right. In your example I can select the text even in Chrome. So I guess this is the intended behavior. I will investigate this a bit more. Coming back.

Comment: @niiyeboah Thanks, this helped to pin down the problem. I happened to experiment with `delegatesFocus:true` (see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom). Removing this made the content in the web component selectable by the user.

Comment: @niiyeboah And since this parameter is experimental I think I will skip the bug report for now.